# PowerMockito mock static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I searched quite a lot but could not find a solution.

Fist my versions:
I am using JUnit4.4, mockito-2.0.0-beta, powermock-module-junit4-1.6.6 and powermock-mockito-1.6.6.

I try to mock a static method to run a unit test independently.

My SUT is kept very simply so far:

```
    Player m_player;
    IView m_view;

    public void play(){
        m_player = PlayerDAO.jaxbXMLToObject();
        m_view.showMenu();
    }
```

My static Method is a simple XML-Parser which should not be called:

```
public class PlayerDAO {

    private static final String File = "src/main/resources/Player.xml";

    public static Player jaxbXMLToObject() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Should not get invoked!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And my actual Testclass:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


import main.java.controller.GameController;
import main.java.dao.PlayerDAO;
import main.java.model.Player;
import main.java.view.ConsoleView;
import main.java.view.IView;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class GameControllerTest {

    GameController sut;
    IView view;

    @Test
    public void shouldShowMenu() {
        IView view = mock(ConsoleView.class);
        sut = new GameController(view);
        sut.play();
        verify(view).showMenu();
    }

    @PrepareForTest(value = {PlayerDAO.class})
    @Test 
    public void shouldTryLoadPlayer(){
        // initialize system
        IView view = mock(ConsoleView.class);
        sut = new GameController(view);

        // stub static method
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(PlayerDAO.class);
        Mockito.when(PlayerDAO.jaxbXMLToObject()).thenReturn(new Player("OriginalTester"));

        //Run
        sut.play();

        //Verify static call
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1));
        PlayerDAO.jaxbXMLToObject();

        //PowerMockito.when(PlayerDAO.jaxbXMLToObject()).thenReturn(new Player("OriginalTester"));

    }

}
```

I tried quite a lot around also using easymock. The actual verification of the call works but the call is still made on the real implementation. Do I need to pass the mocked object to my SUT to be able to make a call on the stub instead of the real one?

I guess it is a simple thing but I am new to PowerMockito.

Kind regards

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Should not get invoked!! is the output while the tests succeed

Comment: Good news I made it work by making a seperate GameControllerStaticTest class where I just test the static methods with PowerMockito but not the menu anymore. Now it works all fine. Something must have interfered the mocking.